# API 302 error when calling in the browser

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call the Instagram APi to get the total followers of an account.

```
'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com:3000
access-control-expose-headers: X-IG-Set-WWW-Claim
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-language: en
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src data: blob: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbsbx.com https://*.giphy.com; font-src data: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com; media-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.fbcdn.net; manifest-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; script-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob:; style-src 'self' https://*.www.instagram.com https://www.instagram.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://api.instagram.com https://i.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com wss://edge-chat.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd blob:; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com; frame-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.instagram.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://web.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://m.facebook.com; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 05:53:11 GMT
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
location: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: ig_did=3E55C6AE-C59A-41E6-8157-6D58413F75FC; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 16-Feb-2023 05:53:11 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=63072000; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: mid=YCtdxwAEAAGVuv6u5ThHTsxmYuOU; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 16-Feb-2023 05:53:11 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; Path=/; Secure
set-cookie: ig_nrcb=1; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Wed, 16-Feb-2022 05:53:11 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/; Secure
status: 302
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
x-aed: 38
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-ig-push-state: c2
x-xss-protection: 0
```

Request Header

```
:authority: www.instagram.com
:method: GET
:path: /virat.kohli/?__a=1
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
origin: http://example.com:3000
referer: http://example.com:3000
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
```

Do I need to set any Headers to do a cross-origin API call?

Comment: 302 is a redirect, not an error.

Comment: @Evert when I copy and paste API url in the browser it gives back the required JSON. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `Location` header provides a hint as to what instagram is telling you what you should do.